# Show Command Prompt Output with BackgroundWorker.Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a program that executes a batch file using an asynchronous background worker. Here is the code:

```
public static void Execute(CmdObj obj, bool batch)
{
    CmdObj = obj;

    var theWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    theWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerCompleted;
    theWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    if(batch)
    {
        theWorker.DoWork += WorkerBatchWork;
    }else{
        theWorker.DoWork += WorkerCommandWork;
    }
    theWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

}

private static void WorkerBatchWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    RunBatch(CmdObj);
}

private static void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var temp = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
    if (temp != null)
        ProgramPath = temp.Substring(6);

    WriteLog(CmdObj.Activity, false);
    WriteLog(CmdObj.Error, true);

    CmdObj.TheButton.Enabled = true;
}

private static void RunBatch(CmdObj obj)
{
    var process = new Process();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                        {
                            FileName = obj.SrcFile,
                            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                            CreateNoWindow = false,
                            RedirectStandardInput = true,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                            RedirectStandardError = true,
                            UseShellExecute = false
                        };


    try
    {
        if (!obj.SrcFile.ToLower().Trim().EndsWith(".bat"))
            throw new FileLoadException("Not a valid .bat file",obj.SrcFile);

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        //obj.Activity = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        obj.Error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj.Exception = ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        process.Close();
    }
}

class CmdObj
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string SrcFile { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
    public Button TheButton { get; set; }
}
```

So when I run this program and choose a batch file to execute, I get a blank CMD window. Is there some way to show the output in the CMD window when my program executes the batch file? Alternatively, if I could have the CMD output sent to a textbox or some other control (in real-time), that would work as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but may you please describe what does `CmdObj` refer to? :)

Comment: Yes sorry, updated code above. It is just a container I wrote.

Comment: I am adding more code, since the above RunBatch is not called directly. This includes the BackgroundWorker declaration. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for this, I've found the solution! I'll post my answer in a minute :)

Comment: Oh ok, well I did anyway. Perhaps it will be useful to someone else in the future!

Comment: The problem is with the following line `RedirectStandardInput = true,`. Is it important to use this in your application? I'm trying to find out why this is causing problems

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18837/discussion-between-anders-and-picrofo-egy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have one of the following properties set to `true`, you'll get a blank black Window

```
RedirectStandardInput
RedirectStandardOutput
RedirectStandardError
```

This will actually happen because you've told your application to receive/send the output/input from the target process

I see that you were trying to get the output from the batch file using this line

```
//obj.Activity = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Unfortunately, this won't work unless you set `RedirectStandardOutput` to `True` so that your application would have the ability to read the output from the target batch file. Otherwise, the output will be empty

**Example**

```
private void RunBatch(CmdObj obj)
{
    var process = new Process();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = obj.SrcFile,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true, //This is required if we want to get the output
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };


    try
    {

        if (!obj.SrcFile.ToLower().Trim().EndsWith(".bat"))
        throw new FileLoadException("Not a valid .bat file",obj.SrcFile);

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        obj.Activity = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //Get the output from the target process
        obj.Error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj.Exception = ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        process.Close(); //Terminate the process after getting what is required
    }
}
```

**Notice that**: `UseShellExecute` must be `False` in order to use `RedirectStandardOutput`

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to call

```
 process.BeginErrorReadLine();
 process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

after process starts?
I had some problems without this if I remember right.